# Unable to cast COM object

Tags: c#, .net

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type ' \a. \a'.
>
> This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the > > interface with IID '{39C13A4D-011E-11D0-9675-0020AFD8ADB3}' failed due to the following error:
>
> The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA).

Anyone has idea about this exception?

Comment: What platform are you running this on? That looks like a DCOM error

Comment: What's with the bogus interface type names?

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason is the COM server was running in a separate process and crashed when the `QueryInterface()` call asked for an unsupported interface. If that's the case it should be addressed by the COM server supplier.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got a COM Object from somewhere else and you are trying to do a QueryInterface on that COM Object for some interface. The COM Server to which this COM Object belongs cannot be instantiated due to one reason or another. An RPC Server failure can be caused due to several reasons.

One probable reason might be that DCOM Tunneling is not enabled for this COM Server. [Link](http://ezinearticles.com/?How-to-Fix-The-RPC-Server-Is-Unavailable-Easily&id=5048827)

However, you will have to show us your code if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue. Aamir's answer saved us. We found out our case is caused by the registry corruption. So we ask help from tech guy, and recovery the registry. Not sure, which registy is corrupted for your case, FYI, ours is DB connection string.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please consider writing a comment instead